# Extract angular routing's paths into separate file

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

Angular routes are typically defined and used like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "register", component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
  // more...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export default class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I don't want to move the routes to a separate file - *I want to move the paths only*.

So I want to extract the `"register"` and `"login"` magic strings and put them somewhere, and then do this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: config.routes.register, component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: config.routes.login, component: LoginComponent },
  // more...
];
```

I have a `Configuration` class I added to DI, and I inject it wherever I need it. I want to add the paths there, if possible.

Some options:

1. I could use static properties on that config class, but that is a hack and harder to test.
2. I could do `const config = new Configuration();` and use it in `routes` like above - but what if it also needs to be part of the IOC container as it has its own dependencies?
3. From @DenisPupyrev's answer: use enums. But like option 2, this means the strings must be encoded in one place without needing dependencies (i.e. no DI).

All those are good options. But what is the cleanest way to extract the magic strings, and also use DI?

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve. `I could use static properties on that config class, but that is a hack and harder to test` - to test what? The route testing does not care about your static vs DI managed strings. Could you provide example where you *fail* to test something because of that? The paths are not the part of DI, so, if you really want to put DI in place, just provide the routes dynamically via some injection factory or using `router.resetConfig()`. I mean, you want your static variable `routes` to refer to non-static properties, this is just logically impossible

Comment: @smnbbrv I never said that. I did say that I prefer to avoid statics unless necessary. My thoughts were, being that I'm new to angular, that maybe there is a way to perform the routing config without using the decorator, because then I can do it cleanly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TypeScript you have a great opportunity to use "Enums".

**Routes.ts**

```
export enum Routes {
  LOGIN = 'login',
  REGISTER = 'register',
  ...
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { Routes } from './path/to/Routes';
...
{ path: Routes.LOGIN, component: LoginComponent }
```

**UPD:**

If you need DI, you can use special service:

**route.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class RouteService {
  routes = {};

  constructor() {
    this.addRoute('login');
  }

  addRoute(route: string) {
    this.routes[route] = route;
  }

  get ROUTES() {
    return this.routes;
  }
}
```

**any.component.ts**

```
import { RouteService } from './path/to/route.service';
...
constructor(private routeService: RouteService) {}
...
anyMethod() {
  this.routeService.ROUTES.login;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is another good option, and I'll add it to the list above. Note though that this is similar the to the statics option, in that it requires all data to be encoded within the enum as-is. It won't work in the case you need to put it through DI for some dependencies.